# Postfix tries to connect to the domain instead of the hostname

Tags: postfix

I have posted this question on ServerFault, but it's as relevant to this site, so copying it here because I'm desperate.

I have several problems with my Postfix configuration. Let's start by this one: in the Postfix logs, Postfix tries to connect (SMTP) to `example.org` instead of `mailer.example.org`. `example.org` is another computer.

Note: I replaced below `example.org` by a domain I own. DNS resolution for both `example.org` (a computer running a web server) and `mailer.example.org` (the computer running postfix) is correct.

The test trying to send an email:

```
ubuntu@mailer:~$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mailer.example.org ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo mailer.example.org
250-mailer.example.org
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
mail from: <root@example.org>
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: <foo@example.org>
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
asdfasdf
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 3AB5A41927
```

/var/log/mail.log:

```
Sep  6 20:10:15 mailer postfix/smtpd[2785]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep  6 20:10:23 mailer postfix/smtp[2779]: connect to example.org[54.229.20.238]:25: Connection timed out
Sep  6 20:10:23 mailer postfix/smtp[2779]: 253C641852: to=<foo@example.org>, relay=none, delay=1059, delays=1029/0.02/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to example.org[54.229.20.238]:25: Connection timed out)
Sep  6 20:10:40 mailer postfix/smtpd[2785]: 3AB5A41927: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep  6 20:10:48 mailer postfix/cleanup[2789]: 3AB5A41927: message-id=<20130906201040.3AB5A41927@mailer.example.org>
Sep  6 20:10:48 mailer postfix/qmgr[2776]: 3AB5A41927: from=<root@example.org>, size=422, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  6 20:10:50 mailer postfix/smtpd[2785]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
local_recipient_maps =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination =
myhostname = mailer.example.org
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = $mydomain
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /mnt/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 51200000
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 5000
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

Comment: Have you check DNS records for example.org as seen by postfix? `dig MX example.com`

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip: I was missing the DNS MX record from `example.org` to `mailer.example.org`. Thanks for the help! What about if you add it as an answer, that I will accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check DNS records for example.org as seen by postfix.

```
dig MX example.com
```

DNS setup/visibility may different than you assume.

Comment: @Braiam Actually, this is an answer (it is intended as one, that is), and it solved the problem, and  was posted as the solution [at the OP's request](http://askubuntu.com/questions/342334/postfix-tries-to-connect-to-the-domain-instead-of-the-hostname/342521#comment437878_342334). Sometimes the question mark can be deceptive. **Andrzej A. Filip**: With that said, and even though this *is* a real answer now, I recommend expanding this with an explicit explanation of how to add the necessary record.

Comment: It is hard to tell "how to add the DNS record" without knowing DNS server or DNS service provider you use (some offer custom web interface).

Comment: Indeed, and OP is vague enough. Also @EliahKagan , in the LQR queue, we can't see comments of the questions, that's why I interpreted it as a comment.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Right, but even general information to that effect might help set some other people with similar problems--some of whom may well be less knowledgeable than the author of this question--on the right path. Of course, it's your choice.